# JSF Ajax call is out of context

Tags: html, ajax, jsf, xhtml, facelets

I have a Facelet which has a div called `"gameinfo"`, by clicking on a certain button this div should be reloaded with Ajax.

**Problem:**

The call does't work, it throws the following error:

`<f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'gameinfo' - cannot locate it in the context of the component dice`

I don't know how to fix it, maybe the div needs to be nearer the button, or maybe only elements in the h: namespace can be called with ajax?

**Code:**

```
            <div id="gameinfo" class="info">
                <h2>Spielinformationen</h2>
                <table summary="Diese Tabelle zeigt Informationen zum aktuellen Spiel">
                    <tr><th id="leaderLabel" class="label">F&uuml;hrender</th><td id="leader" class="data"><h:outputText value="#{spiel.getLeader()}" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><th id="roundLabel" class="label">Runde</th><td id="round" class="data"><h:outputText value="#{spiel.getRound()}" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><th id="timeLabel" class="label">Zeit</th><td id="time" class="data"><h:outputText value="#{spiel.getTime()}" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><th id="computerScoreLabel" class="label">W&uuml;rfelergebnis <em>Super C</em></th><td id="computerScore" class="data"><h:outputText value="#{spiel.getComputerScore()}" /></td></tr>
                </table>  
                <h2>Spieler</h2>
                <table summary="Diese Tabelle listet die Namen der Spieler auf">
                    <tr><th id="player1NameLabel" class="label">Spieler 1</th><td id="player1Name" class="data">Super Mario</td></tr>
                    <tr><th id="player2NameLabel" class="label">Spieler 2</th><td id="player2Name" class="data">Super C</td></tr>
                </table>          
            </div>
```

And the Ajax Call:

```
            <div id="player" class="player">
                <h2 class="accessibility">W&uuml;rfelbereich</h2>
                <span class="accessibility">An der Reihe ist</span><div id="currentPlayerName">Super Mario</div>
                <h:form id="form">
                    <h:commandButton id="dice" alt="W&uuml;rfel mit einer Eins" image="resources/img/wuerfel1.png" action="#{spiel.dice()}" tabindex="4" title="W&uuml;rfel mit einer Eins">
                        <f:ajax render="gameinfo" />
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:form>
            </div>
```

Edit: solved! I changed the `<div>` into `<h:Panelgroup>` and deleted the `<h:form>` in which the button was.

Comment: If you deleted the wrapping `<h:form>` of the button and only then it started to work it means that there was already a `<h:form>` wrapping that deleted `<h:form>` (you had nested forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<f:ajax` should point to a JSF component

Replace

```
<div id="gameinfo" class="info">
```

With

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="gameinfo" styleClass="info">
```

---

`<h:panelGroup layout="block"` will turn into a html `div`

Comment: The button is in a h:form, "gameinfo" not

Comment: inspect with your browser for the real id of the `gameinfo` it might be inside some naming container...

Comment: ok I solved it, I just deleted the `<h:form>` in which the button was, now it works :) thx for your help

Comment: no, just a single form, but strangly enough as long as the button was in the form ajax could only call elements inside the form, or the form itself, not to elements outside.